# custom blur not working correctly [AngularJS]

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to create notifications something like this:

http://plnkr.co/edit/GbFioFDNb2OC4ZjARQTp?p=preview

But I am unsuccesful to integrade it in my script, because when I click outside notification box nothing happend.

Here is my script:

```
'use strict';
var app = angular.module('notifications',['ngRoute'], function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('<%');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('%>');


})
        .controller('NotificationController', function($scope, $http) {
            $http.get("/api/notification")
            .success(function (response) {
                $scope.notys = response;
            });

            $scope.notifications = {
                visible: false
              };
            $scope.showNotifications = function(flag) {
                $scope.notifications.visible = flag;
              };



          })
           .directive('customBlur', function(){
            return {
              restrict: 'A',
              scope: {
                'customBlur': '='
              },
              link: function(scope, element, attr) {
                element.on('click', function(event){
                  var targetAttr = angular.element(event.target).attr('custom-blur');
                  console.log(targetAttr);
                  if (typeof targetAttr !== 'undefined') {
                    scope.$apply(function(){
                      scope.customBlur = false;
                    });
                  } 
                });
              }
            };
          });
```

Problem is when I click outside notifcation box it not return anything but shuld return `notification.visible` if I click into notification box it return `undefined` as expected.

that is result for: `console.log(targetAttr);`

Comment: can you provide your plnkr ? Instead of current one. But by comparing code all I see is that your if statement is not same : `if (typeof targetAttr !== 'undefined' && scope.customBlur) {` . But this is just a guess. Your plunkr will be more helpful. Thank you.

Comment: This part is importante `typeof targetAttr !== 'undefined'` when I click outside of notification box `targetAttr ` variable shoud be equal `notification.visible`, so after I click outside box `typeof targetAttr` shoud be defined but in my app that part not working... When I click outside box nothing happed.

Comment: I think there is something wrong with your module name and controller name. Fix those and everything will start working again. See console and try fixing error which you get. I will soon post my answer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran your code in plunkr and tried to fix the error.
All I found is that your module name and controller name were not same.

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module demo due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'demo' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.2/$injector/nomod?p0=demo
```

This error says that angular is not able to find the module 'demo'. So I made changes to HTML here. This line:

```
<html ng-app="notifications">
```

After that I got this error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module notifications due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ngRoute due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ngRoute' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

This says that ngRoute which you are using here `angular.module('notifications',['ngRoute'], function($interpolateProvider) {` is not available. So I just removed it. (just to fix the error.).So I did changes to js. This line:

```
angular.module('notifications',[], function($interpolateProvider) {
```

ok After that I got this error:

```
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'Ctrl' is not a function, got undefined
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.2/ng/areq?p0=Ctrl&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
```

Which says that Ctrl is not defined  properly.So I made changes to HTML again.This line

```
 <body ng-controller="NotificationController">
```

ok. After fixing all this I found no more error. and your plunker started working again. 
you can see the plunker here : [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fUplX4K0FB8GmmVgH16T?p=preview)

Hope this helps you. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, but not that problem problem is with my app, angular custom blur not working correctly..